# Random meetings in large graphs: efficient way of adding or deleting edges of a graph in R

Tags: r, igraph, edges

I am trying to find an efficient way of simulating random meetings in a graph in R using igraph.

I managed to do it using the code below in which I assume edges appear with some probability (prob.meet) and add them to an (pre-existent) empty graph of same size.

However, for large graphs this is not efficient. Plus, I repeat this process over an over.

- The first layer of inefficiency is the random selection of edges
  using the `rbin()` function (amounts to 25% of the time)
- The second layer of inefficiency is adding edges to an existent empty
  graph using the `add_edges()` function (amounts to 75% of the time)

Any suggestion on how to improve efficiency?

Here is what I tried:

1. First, I create a random graph:

```
library(igraph)

nodes = 5
g1 <- barabasi.game(nodes)
EL1 <- get.edgelist(g1, names=FALSE)
```

2. Second, I assume the edges pop up with probability "prob.meet", and add them to an empty graph. The reason I do that is to force `g_meet` to conform in size with `g1`.

```
prob.meet = 0.5

EL_meet <- matrix(EL1[(as.logical(rbinom(nrow(EL1), 1, prob.meet))),],
                  nrow=2,byrow = TRUE
                  )

g_meet <- make_empty_graph(n = nodes) %>%
            add_edges(EL_meet)
```

Comment: How large is large? A couple hundred nodes, a couple thousand or perhaps millions?

Comment: @Tim, for the time being, a couple thousand. Anything that works for something around 100,000 nodes should do it.

Comment: What happens after you create `g_meet` in your workflow? What is a "random meeting", is it an edge between two nodes? Or is it a path between two nodes? Or something else?

Comment: @emilliman5, nothing specific. It is all normal. The thing is: I have to repeat this process multiple times and any difference in terms of millisecond counts. A random meeting is an edge between two nodes.

Comment: If a "random meeting" is an edge between two nodes then why not just compute random meetings mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `delete_edges` like below

```
g1 %>%
  delete_edges(which(runif(ecount(.)) > prob.meet))
```

where

- `runif() > prob.meet` yields random logical array indicating the removals.
- `ecount` returns the number of edges in graph `g1`.
- `which` returns the edge ids that should be removed.

## Benchmarking

```
f_OP <- function() {
  EL1 <- get.edgelist(g1, names = FALSE)
  EL_meet <- matrix(EL1[(as.logical(rbinom(nrow(EL1), 1, prob.meet))), ],
    nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE
  )
  make_empty_graph(n = nodes) %>%
    add_edges(EL_meet)
}

f_Tim <- function() {
  delete_non_meeting_edges <- function(g, prob.meet) {
    g <- set_edge_attr(g, "meet", E(g), runif(gsize(g)) < prob.meet)
    delete_edges(g, E(g)[!meet])
  }
  delete_non_meeting_edges(g1, prob.meet)
}

f_TIC <- function() {
  g1 %>%
    delete_edges(which(runif(ecount(.)) > prob.meet))
}


nodes <- 100000
g1 <- barabasi.game(nodes)
prob.meet <- 0.5
microbenchmark(
  f_OP(),
  f_Tim(),
  f_TIC(),
  unit = "relative"
)
```

and you will see

```
Unit: relative
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  f_OP() 1.584501 1.583768 1.631061 1.618017 1.675887 1.535542   100
 f_Tim() 1.517888 1.520832 1.597230 1.584570 1.679498 1.585434   100
 f_TIC() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

Comment: Thx a lot, @ThomasIsCoding! Besides, your `f_TIC` function is way shorter than ours.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find, there are only marginal speed gains to be made.

[It has been reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432252/16094100) that using `runif()` is faster than using `rbinom()` in your particular use case. Running it on my system seems to confirm this:

```r
prob.meet <- 0.5
system.time({rbinom(1000000, 1, prob.meet)})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.10    0.00    0.11
system.time({runif(1000000) < prob.meet})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.05    0.00    0.04
```

However, as you can see, we are talking about just a couple hundredths of a second of improvement when doing a million random draws.

An alternative to adding the edges to a new empty graph would be deleting the non-meeting edges. That would look something like this:

```r
library(igraph)

delete_non_meeting_edges <- function(g, prob.meet = 0.5) {
  g <- set_edge_attr(g, "meet", E(g), runif(gsize(g)) < prob.meet)
  delete_edges(g, E(g)[!meet])
}

## Usage
g <- barabasi.game(1000000)
delete_non_meeting_edges(g)
```

However, the above is not really faster. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029574/16094100) suggests that mutations of igraph objects are inherently slow, due to the underlying data structures. In the linked answer vectorisation is suggested as a way to speed up mutations, but both the example you provided as the code above already use this.

So I am afraid that if you are using igraph, there is not much more speed to be gained.

Comment: good point to use `runif`, which is more efficient. Upvoted!

Comment: @Tim, you made a great contribution! I had to vote for ThomasIsCoding since his code beat yours. In any event, you certainly put him on the track. Thx a ton!